# SF Symbols Multicolored icons

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sf-symbols

Im making an app with weather icons, and i wanted to use apple's SF Symbols! At WWDC2020 they released multicolred ones.

So my question is, why are my icons appearing in black like so:

[image]

I have set the rendering mode to alwaysOriginal. And it does nothing. If i set it to template it becomes blue, like the default tint color.

```
currentConditionImageView.image = UIImage(systemName: "cloud.sun.fill")!.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
```

But according to the SF Symbols app, the symbol should look like this:

[image]

Has anyone encountered this Problem, and how did you solve it?
Im looking forward to your answers!

Comment: Please post the code that you have for the SFSymbol.

Comment: @Todd i have edited the question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rule is:

> In a *template* environment, such as a button, if you apply the `.alwaysOriginal` rendering mode to a multicolor symbol image, its inherent colors will appear.

But an image view is not a template environment. Try making this image the image (not the background image) of a UIButton.

[image]

If you put a multicolored image in a non-template environment, like an image view, you are basically misusing it if you make it `.alwaysOriginal`. You should just make it `.alwaysTemplate` and accept it as a monochrome image adopting the tint color.

[image]

Comment: Thank you @matt ! Is there some workaround, or should i just export the icons as image and then use them that way?

Comment: I have tried, it does not work even for UIButton, have the same problem of showing black color sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to create a multicolored SF Symbol for use in a non-template environment like `UIImageView`.

For a white checkmark on a green background, for example:

[image]

Try this:

```
let config = UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(paletteColors: [.white, UIColor.green])
  
let multicolorCheckmarkImage = UIImage(systemName: "checkmark.circle.fill")?.withConfiguration(config)
        
self.checkmarkImageView.image = multicolorCheckmarkImage
```

Comment: You can remove the use of `.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)` and it will still give the correct results.

Comment: Thanks, @HangarRash - you're absolutely right.  I'll edit my answer.